# How to set array's member property via other one

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

Consider the next code:

```
    public Color TotalColor { get; set; }
    public string TotalColorName
    {
        get => TotalColor.ToString();
        set => TotalColor = Color.FromHex(value);
    }
```

It works good. Now I'm trying to implement the same approach for two arrays:

```
    public string[] AreaColorNames { set; } = new string[3];
    public Color[] AreaColors { get; } = new string[3];
```

How should I write the setter for `AreaColorNames`? It should be something like this:

```
AreaColorNames
{
    set
    { 
      AreaColors[index] = Color.FromHex(value);
    }
}
```

but we don't have an `index` parameter in setters. Is there some workaround?
Thank you.

**Edit**

In my case a number of colors can be different, so I can't use approach "left-middle-right".

Let me explain what I'm trying to do. I'm developing an *inhouse* library for reading definite file format. Consumers will use it from different apps, e.g. desktop and mobile. So I don't want to read a color value itself, because in one system type `Color` is described in `System.Drawing`, in other - in `Xamarin.Forms` etc. I'm thinking I can have a `ColorName` property in interface which will be used as function parameter and appropriate setters in every implementation. Because library is dedicated for using in our own apps only, I couldn't bother about wrong using - it will be restricted by internal arrangements.

Comment: Why not just an array of whatever class `TotalColorName` belongs to?

Comment: Because this division better describes a real object I communicate with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could go about this. You could get really fancy using a custom collection type with [indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers).

But I'd recommend finding the simplest approach based on what you actually need. For example, think about how AreaColorNames is used: does it really make sense for someone to set a specific index to a specific string? That sounds like you're inviting people to make mistakes. What if they provide an index higher than 2? What if they provide a string that doesn't represent a hex value?

If you know that you've only got three "Areas", is that an essential part of your model, which you can come up with a name for? For example:

```
public class AreaColors
{
  public Color LeftColor {get;set;}
  public Color MiddleColor {get;set;}
  public Color RightColor {get;set;}
  public IReadOnlyCollection<string> TotalColors => new[]{LeftColor, MiddleColor, RightColor}
}
```

I'd argue that coming up with a `Color` from a hex value should be done prior to setting it on an object like this: the writer of the consuming code should be forced to think about things like what they should do if the given string is not a valid color.

Comment: I updated my question because explanation becomes too long :)

Comment: I'll try to use idea "Indexing using other values" from the article you gave me. Thank you.